# ProducerTemplate and Direct:start in camel

Tags: apache, apache-camel, endpoint

My camel route is :

```
from("direct:start")
.to("http://myhost/mypath");
```

I used :

```
ProducerTemplate template; 
template.sendBody("direct:start", "This is a test message");
```

to send the exchange. I am getting following exception:

```
No consumers available on endpoint: Endpoint[direct://start].
```

How can i receive the same exchange in direct:start endpoint?

Answer (score 2):

The reason you get this error is because you have not configured a `Route` that starts from `direct:start`.

If you have configured the `Route`, but did not mention it in your original query, then the next step to try is to first start the Camel Context, before calling the `sendBody` method.

```
camelContext.start();
template.sendBody("direct:start", "This is a test message");
```

Hope this resolves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I know this a very old question. But writing this for anyone who're still getting this kind of issue.

Scenario: During the process of a http GET method call, I am fetching some data from DB in the middle of the process and putting the data as message on to an artemis producer.

Firstly, if you're using camel with spring - you don't need to create any camel context at all. Because spring is smart enough to create camel context for you with below dependencies.

Few necessary dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-artemis</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>2.24.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-jaxb-starter</artifactId>
    <version>2.24.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-jms</artifactId>
    <version>2.24.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-jackson-starter</artifactId>
    <version>2.24.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.24.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-amqp</artifactId>
    <version>2.24.2</version>
</dependency>
```

So to fix it, I created a class that extends RouteBuilder class from camel library. In this builder, I created a dummy consumer and used it to send message to an actual producer. My destination is an artemis producer endpoint.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule;
import org.apache.camel.LoggingLevel;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.component.jackson.JacksonDataFormat;
import org.apache.camel.spi.DataFormat;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    private DataFormat marshalDataFormat;

    public MyRouteBuilder(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
        marshalDataFormat = new JacksonDataFormat(objectMapper, MyClass.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("direct:imaginary-consumer")
                .marshal(marshalDataFormat)
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Message ready to send is ${body}")
                .to("producer:message-data")
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Message has been sent successfully to topic.");
    }

}
```

Below snippet is in any implementation class that carries the message body. This method takes message data and send it to the imaginary/dummy consumer we created in MyRouteBuilder class. The router class gets invoked and sends the message to the destination (producer here). It can be to http endpoints as well.

```
@Autowired
private ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

public void sendMessage(Map<String, MyClass> messageBody) {
   producerTemplate.sendBody("direct:imaginary-consumer", messageBody);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is also posted on the Apache Camel mailing list, where its active being discussed.
http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/ProducerTemplate-and-direct-start-in-camel-tp5730558.html

Comment: I only asked same question on camel mailing list. PS: if you downvoted my question for same reason, i feel, you shouldn't :)